# How to order in SQL by name with latest id?

Tags: sql, select

I have a problem. I have big data table with 300+ users (as `garazas_id`) for every user I have multiple rows created over the past 3 years. I will order it by `garazas_id` and will see only record with latest id for every row (or with latest date it will be the same result).

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT id = MAX(id), garazas_id, sk_rad, datums 
FROM `elektr_apmaks`
GROUP BY garazas_id 
ORDER BY garazas_id + 0;
```

Order is ok, but results in each row is with the earlier id.

Comment: Show a sample of the table with all the columns. Tell more clearly how you want to select the rows

Comment: "sql" as a tag is almost useless - we need to know which database you use as they all have differences in their sql syntax - and you want the syntax that you can use - so please **edit the tags and choose the database** e.g. mysql sql-server bigquery postgres

Comment: My table is wery simple:
Gar. Nr. Sk. rād. Datums
0 1633 2022-05-25
1 8914 2021-09-12
10 1161 2022-04-06
100 1331 2022-04-13
101 66 2022-04-13
102 1521 2022-04-13
103 787 2022-04-13
All data is correct, only i need them to be in order 1,2,3,4…

Code is:
select
       ea.*
from `elektr_apmaks` as ea
inner join (
    SELECT
           max(id) as id
         , garazas_id 
    FROM `elektr_apmaks`
    GROUP BY garazas_id
    ) as mx on ea.id = mx.id
ORDER BY garazas_id

If i add to the last line:
 ORDER BY garazas_id + 0 then it stop working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you may be using MySQ, the following should work in all versions of that

```
select
       ea.*
from `elektr_apmaks` as ea
inner join (
    SELECT
           max(id) as id
         , garazas_id 
    FROM `elektr_apmaks`
    GROUP BY garazas_id
    ) as mx on ea.id = mx.id
ORDER BY garazas_id
```

**IF**  you cAN use `row_number() over()` (if you have V8 or later of MySQL)

```
select
       ea.*
from (
    SELECT
           *
         , row_number() over(partition by garazas_id 
                             order by id DESC) as rn
    FROM `elektr_apmaks`
    GROUP BY garazas_id
    ) as ea
where rn = 1
ORDER BY garazas_id
```

Comment: Yes this first works! :) Only results are 1; 10; 100; 101... not 1,2,3... But when i add ORDER BY garazas_id + 0  then it stop working.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following as well if date matters:

```
select TOP 1 * from TableName order by dateColumn desc;
```